# Error while submitting the data "jwt must be provided"

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, express-jwt

The server is running in development mode on port 8080
The database connected successfully.

I have created an admin panel and want to create categories. For this, I created a **create categories** method. when I fill all the fields and press the submit button, getting this error instead of a response.

```
at module.exports \[as verify\] (C:\\Users\\AMANULLAH\\Desktop\\shopping app\\backend\\node_modules\\jsonwebtoken\\verify.js:60:17)
at requireSignIn (C:\\Users\\AMANULLAH\\Desktop\\shopping app\\backend\\middlewares\\authmiddleware.js:9:28)
at Layer.handle \[as handle_request\] (C:\\Users\\AMANULLAH\\Desktop\\shopping app\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\\Users\\AMANULLAH\\Desktop\\shopping app\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\\Users\\AMANULLAH\\Desktop\\shopping app\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\route.js:114:3)  
at Layer.handle \[as handle_request\] (C:\\Users\\AMANULLAH\\Desktop\\shopping app\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\\Users\\AMANULLAH\\Desktop\\shopping app\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (C:\\Users\\AMANULLAH\\Desktop\\shopping app\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:346:12)
at next (C:\\Users\\AMANULLAH\\Desktop\\shopping app\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:280:10)
at Function.handle (C:\\Users\\AMANULLAH\\Desktop\\shopping app\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:175:3)
```

Comment: share your code also.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of `jwt` as mentioned in the error.

> jwt must be provided

This happens when the coming token is null or empty. ( also check it's expiration time though it is not related to the issue ).